# Dlookup in a form with 2 subforms (The requirement for the dlookup is in the second subform)

Tags: ms-access-2007

Access 2007

```
Form Name is: MineLocationQuery1
1st Subform name is:MineExtractionSubform
2nd Subform name is: ExtractionLineSubform2
```

I am trying to use dlookup to get check a value in a table and then multiply it by another value. It works with: NO Subform and with 1 Subform.  But when I add 2 subforms I cannot get it to work.

Here is what I have tried so far

Simple form lookup that works:

```
=DLookUp("[Price]","[Resource]","[AtomicRef]='" & [Forms]![ExtractionLine]![AtomicRef] & "'")*[Tonnage]
```

Here is the working example from a form created with 1 subform:

```
=DLookUp("[Price]","[Resource]","[AtomicRef]='" & [Forms]![MineExtraction1]![ExtractionLineSubform]![AtomicRef] & "'")*[Tonnage]
```

And here is 1 of the many attempts I have made with 2 subforms and it is not working.

```
=DLookUp("[Price]","[Resource]","[AtomicRef]='" & Forms![MineLocationQuery1]!MineExtractionSubform.Form!ExtractionLineSubform2.Form.AtomicRef & "'")*[Tonnage]
```

What am I doing wrong other than getting tired and frustrated at copying and pasting many attempts into the worths textbox control source and repeatedly getting #Name errors

Comment: You have nested subforms, is that correct?

Comment: Yes i have nested subforms I followed this procedure:  http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=72479                                                                                                                                        to create them as 1:M form then a sub form that is 1:M from the main form and a 2nd subform that is 1:M from the 1st subform.

Comment: That is not very clear. You cannot have a subform contained in a subform unless the 1st subform is a single form. Do you mean you have two subforms on the main form but the forms are correlated? Also, I wonder bout the value of the whole thing, because [AtomicRef] will change as you select each row in subform2, is that what you want?

Comment: The main form is a single form based on Mine location (Mine location is the equivalent of the Customer entity ). The 1st subform on the main form  is the Mine extraction subform. (Mine extraction is similar to customer order) So main form is the 1 and the first subform is the many. As 1 mine has many extractions which is similar to 1 customer who  has many orders.

Comment: The second subform is the extraction line (whats been dug out of the ground) it is similar to an order line(s). So 1 order Has many order lines and looking at it hierarchically 1 mine many extractions 1 extraction has many extraction lines which is similar to the all to familiar 1 customer has many orders and 1 order has many order lines.

Comment: As for subform 2 each extraction line contains 1 atomic ref as you can only dig so much of 1 type of resource out of the ground in  1 day , you can dig multiple resource types out in 1 day which make up the order line(s) or in my case extraction line(s) but you do not get repeating resource codes as what is dug out in a day is that order and associated order lines  for the day. Next day new order new dig = next record in database.

Comment: Yes, I understand that and the standard solution is correlated subforms, not nested subforms eg. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13387144/2548

Comment: I do not believe you should be using DLookUp in the main form in this case. You should be working in subform2, which makes the reference to atomicref very easy indeed.

Comment: i may have explained it incorrect as the dlookup i am using is in the second subform and is looking at the table associated with that subform. Its just well not working with 2 subforms, works when its a form on its own and works when i go 1 tier higher and create a 1 order has many order lines form subform setup. But getting the correct syntax with another subform the subform of concern and a main form it aint. Although i am testing what is not being called correctly in the immediate window now as per your solution , will see if it resolves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I wish to refer to a nested subform in a textbox on the main form, I might say:

```
=[SubformControl1].[Form].[SubformControl2].[Form].[AControlName]
```

Note that this uses the name of the subform control and Form as a reference to the object contained by the control.

So this (split for ease of reading) looks right:

```
=DLookUp("[Price]","[Resource]","[AtomicRef]='" & Forms![MineLocationQuery1]!
MineExtractionSubform.Form!ExtractionLineSubform2.
Form.AtomicRef & "'")*[Tonnage]
```

However, it is very easy to get names wrong. For example, you may be referring to the form contained, rather than the subform control name. You can use the Expression Builder to troubleshoot, or you can refer to the form bit by bit in the immediate window (Ctrl+G) to ensure you have the names right. For example:

```
?Forms![MineLocationQuery1].Name
?Forms![MineLocationQuery1]!MineExtractionSubform.Name
```

More information: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

EDIT re comments

If you work in subform 2, as I believe you should in this case, you can simply refer to [atomicref]:

```
=DLookUp("[Price]","[Resource]","[AtomicRef]='" & [atomicref] & "'")
```

Comment: OK and Thank-you will check out the correct name process and the errors in my code to the solution and see if i can get this to work. Watch this space!

Comment: That dlookup worked thank-you , what i learned is not to dlookup then reference from the form to subform 1 then subform 2, when you can simply dlookup from subform 2 to the table that it is associated with to get your required result, summary then Don't overlook the obvious.