# link Child/Master fields with Separate subform

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a problem with a form in a database that i have open.

The form is called Specifiche and inside there are two subform: SSpecifiche and SSDatiSpecifiche.

http://postimage.org/image/alagax8zx/full/

The subform SSpecifiche is connected to the table Dati_Capitolati while SSDatiSpecifiche is connected to the table Codice_Specifica.
These two tables have two fields in relation: Codice specifica with Codice specifica and Nome Tabella with Tabella.
The result should be this: http://postimage.org/image/aefarm47r/

In fact, opening with an Access 97 I have no problems, but in 2010 the right table is empty, it does not load any field. Using the wizard fields do not help me to solve this problem.
Documenting i read that maybe i need to create a query, but I can not understand the proceedings. For me the error is here:

```
LinkChildFields Master: Codice Specifica;[Nome Tabella]
LinkChildFields: Codice Specifica;Tabella
```

I hope I was clear, I thank you for any help

Comment: I am not sure how that worked in Access '97. You need to refer to the name of the subform control in the link fields, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386062/display-many-to-many-relationship-in-continuous-form/13387144#13387144

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but these days I opened the database and I think I know what does not work. 
Studying this page, http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/synchronize/linkedsubforms.asp
I get to be in the same situation. In fact, I noticed that the main form there is a hidden text box. And it is this that does not work, in fact I made ​​visible and reads: # Error.

This text box is called: Nome Tabella and data source control has: =[SSpecifiche].[Forms]![Table Name]

I checked and therefore should be fair, I do not understand then why does not work.