# ACCESS. Go to subform registry based on table selection from another subform

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I need some of your help.

I've created an Access form with this structure:

[image: Forms structure]
Where "Subform 2" is a Table with records (with simplyfied fields of a table), and "Subform 1" is supposed to open detailed info related to the selected registry in "Subform 2" (data source from the same table as subform 2 but with more fields loaded) as well as an option to insert details of a new registry.

The problem is that I don't know how to reffer each one with the other.

The code I've got so far is:
I've put some code in the current() event in SUBFORM 2, to update registry in SUBFORM 1, to make it go to the current record selected, but references are not working.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
' Find the record that matches the selection.
    If IsNull(Me!Form.CurrentRecord) Then Exit Sub

    With Me.Parent![Subform 1 Name].Form.RecorsetClone
      .FindFirst "[Id] = " & Me!Form.CurrentRecord
      If Not .NoMatch Then
         If Me.Parent![Subform 1 Name].Form.Dirty Then Me.Parent![Subform 1 Name].Form.Dirty = False
         Me.Parent![Subform 1 Name].Form.Bookmark = .Bookmark
      Else
         'not found code here'
      End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I'll be very grateful with any help you could give me.
Thanks!

Comment: If this is the [subform 2]'s _Current event, then the Me.Parent is wrong, since Subform 2 has no Parent element.

Try Forms("Parent").Form.[Subform 1].Form.RecordsetClone, see where that takes you.

Comment: @parakmiakos A subform has a parent, it is one of the most useful things about it : `Private Sub Form_Current()
    MsgBox Me.Parent.Name
End Sub`

Comment: There is an easier way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386062/display-many-to-many-relationship-in-continuous-form/13387144#13387144