# Control for display of grouped data

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

For a small in-house project I need to display tabular data grouped by a certain column. It would be nice to be able to expand/collapse the groups. The Group title is a simple text string.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this with standard controls, preferably using data-binding instead of manually populating for example a ListView control?

Comment: Perhaps: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3734331/Access-TreeView-ListView-Basics.htm

Comment: I know about the ListView and TreeView from the past (~2000) but was hoping that something with data binding has evolved since then.

Comment: Not that I know of, I would use two subforms, but that is a completely different approach.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the two-subforms approach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386062/display-many-to-many-relationship-in-continuous-form/13387144#13387144

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to achieve what you need using [SubDatasheets](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/add-a-subdatasheet-HA010266800.aspx) in Access.

Another way to display information, if you don't have too many columns, is to use a tree view.
There is even a [100% VBA one!](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/treeview.asp)